# decrypted value from mysql pdo php

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, pdo

```
$stmt2 = $dbh-> prepare("Select * from encryptme where ".decrypt('encryptedcolumn', $key)." = ?");
$stmt2 -> bindValue(1, $dec, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt2 -> execute();
```

I have `encrypt()` and `decrypt()` i save the data after using `encrypt()` now i want to select the data but i am not able to because the data are encrypted. What I tried is i used the function in the column name but it is not working i get error saying

> Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= '

How can i decrypt the column in the query statement?

Comment: You want to decrypt what comes _back_ from the query don't you? So you need to fetch the value inside encrypted column, _then_ run decrypt on the values.

Comment: what i want is i want to select the decrypted value from the columns.. you the `$dec` it is the decrypted value..i want to select the column `encryptme` for the value of `$dec` but i cant see it since that column is encrypted.. So what i did is i run the function `decrypt()` on column.. but i get error.. How can i decrypt the value in where clause?? @JonStirling

Comment: @JonStirling how can i do that in where clause?

Comment: The contents of the column might be encrypted, but the column name most likely isn't, what would be the point?

Comment: Is the column name encrypted or the column values or both?

Comment: If you encrypt / decrypt algos are in PHP, then you can't decrypt the data in the db without pulling it out first. The alternative is to encrypt the decrypted value you've got and have the WHERE check if the encrypted values match.

Comment: columns values only....example the regular text is `text` it is saved in the `encryptme` column as `sfsdkt582fasf` so in my `where clause` i want `WHERE encryptme = 'text'` but it will be fair since it is not the same right? how to make it correct way @ArtjomB.

Comment: @JonStirling i tried it already but the encrypted value is not always the same they are different always so i cant use it..that is why i thought decrypting will work

Comment: @BrownmanRevival Then I'm not sure you can do what you're asking.

Comment: @JonStirling what do you suggest i do to make it work?

Comment: @BrownmanRevival It depends on your encrypt / decrypt methods I guess.

Comment: @JonStirling last question seen this `dbo.FormatPhone(@Phone);` and `dbo.decrypt(LNAME_HASH)` on some other post what is `dbo` here?

Answer (score 1):

You can not use a php function to decrypt the value in the database while querying. (You can use a database function if it supports the entcryption method however)

You CAN instead send an encrypted parameter to the database to compare it to the encrypted stored value.

After fetching the data you can then decrypt the value to do whatever you need to.

edit after new information:

If you can not reliably encrypt the values in php, you will have to fetch all the data from the database and then decrypt it so you can compare the values.

Comment: i tried it already but the encrypted value is not always the same they are different always so i cant use it..that is why i thought decrypting will work. **You CAN instead send an encrypted parameter to the database to compare it to the encrypted stored value.** i dont understand how to work this out?

Comment: *"You CAN instead send an encrypted parameter to the database to compare it to the encrypted stored value."* - Whether this is possible depends on `encrypt()` and whether it is semantically secure (randomized). If it is, then it's not possible what you're proposing. If it is not, then [ECB](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/14490/13022) is probably used.

Comment: @ArtjomB. yes it is random because i can see in the database the values are different when they are the same data..

Comment: Oh alright. So that means you have to fetch all the data and then compare it in php using decrypt. [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) could be helpful if nobody knows a better way.

Comment: as much as i can i want it on clause so i wont resort on that @Philipp problem is what if i have so many data that will be delay right?

Comment: Yea I see the problem. I'm going to keep looking into this problem, maybe there is a good way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your Solution

```
$stmt2 = $dbh-> prepare("Select * from encryptme where CAST(AES_DECRYPT(encryptedcolumn, 'key') AS CHAR) = ?");
$stmt2 -> bindValue(1, $dec, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt2 -> execute();
```

All the best.

Comment: that is what i tried it give an error...if you check my question you will that i tried it

Comment: Here, `AES_DECRYPT` must be compatible with `encrypt()` (whatever that is). How do you know that it is compatible?